# Error al enviar botones WhatsApp-web.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, whatsapp

Estoy teniendo dos problemas al intentar crear un bot con botones para whatsapp en nodejs. Estoy usando la librería de pedroslopez de whatsapp-web.js
El primer error lo tengo al intentar enviar un botón según lo marca el ejemplo de la documentación oficial de pedro. Y el segundo es que no tengo del todo claro como hacer que el bot inicie con el primer mensaje indistintamente de lo que el cliente, si se lo puede llamar así, escribió como primer mensaje.

El código es el siguiente:

```
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
const { Client, LocalAuth } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const { Message, ClientInfo, Buttons } = require('whatsapp-web.js/src/structures');


 const client = new Client({
    authStrategy: new LocalAuth(),
    puppeteer: { headless: false }
});



client.on('ready', () => {
    console.clear();
    console.log('vinculado correctamente');
});

client.on('qr', qr => {
     console.log('Vincule el QR nuevamente');
     qrcode.generate(qr, { small: true });
});


client.initialize();

client.on('message', msg => {
    console.log('mensaje de: ', msg.from, 'Texto: ', msg.body)
    if (msg.body === 'Hola') {
        let button = new Buttons('Button body', [{ body: 'Aceptar' }, { body: 'rechazar' }], 'title', 'footer');
        client.sendMessage(msg.from, button);
    }
});
```

Al vincularlo y enviarle un Hola, debería enviar dos botones que digan "Aceptar" y "Rechazar. Pero en este caso al ver lo que intenta enviar me encuentro con el mensaje pendiente de envío que dice body, title y demás.
Espero que sepan entender, soy novato en esto aun y desde ya GRACIAS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

pudiste solucionar? yo te recomiendo lo siguiente:

```
npm uninstall whatsapp-web.js
```

y despues ejecuta

```
npm i pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js#fix-buttons-list
```

Funciona botones (whatsapp y whatsapp-bussiness) y List (solo en whatsapp)

```
const button = new Buttons('!Body', [{id:'1', body:'Aceptar'}, {id:'0', body:'Rechazar'}], 'title', 'footer');
```

para leer la respuesta puedes hacer lo siguiente:
en

```
client.on('message', msg => {
      const { from, body, hasMedia, type, selectedButtonId } = msg;
      const _type = type.toLowerCase();
      if(_type=='buttons_response'){
         console.log('selectedButtonId: ', selectedButtonId);
      }else{
      }
})
```

Espero pueda servirte!!! Éxitos